# What is the best practice to programmatically set SQL indexes with Entity-Framework-Code-First

Tags: sql, entity-framework, indexing, ef-code-first

I am using Asp.Net MVC 3, Entity-Framework 4.1 and was wondering if there is any useful way to set SQL indexes programmatically on some columns in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a [Database Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) to create indexes

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        //your logic here
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_Products_Code ON dbo.Products ( Code )");

    }
}
```

Then you can setup the initializer on startup

```
Database.SetInitializer<ProductCatalog>(new MyInitializer());
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I hoped for but it works very well. Thank you. If noone else comes with a better solution I will set your answer as accepted.